# Java Error - Security Exception

Tags: java, jar

When I am trying to load a `JAR` file in the browser, after I clicked on Run Java I am getting the following error message

**SecurityException**

```
com.sub.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource:
https://control.mydomain.com/java/sshterm-applet/SSHTermApplet-signed.jar
```

I tried the following

```
Control Panel>Java>General>Settings>Uncheck Temp Storage
Control Panel>Java>General>Settings>Check Temp Storage
```

But still no use. Can anyone tell me what's the problem

Comment: What is your Java version ?

Comment: @Bishan - 1.7.0_25 VERSION 7 UPDATE 51

Comment: Downgrade Java to version 7 Update 40 or below

Answer (score 1):

A recent turn in security wars is that browsers no longer run unsigned java applets by default, so lots old applets are now broken.  Many will never be fixed because it's both
expensive and a hassle.

You can set your browser to run "insecure" applets anyway (exact details vary).